# App not working in all devices

Tags: android, android-permissions

I made a music player app. It runs properly in some devices but it crashes in some others. I am not able to understand the error. How do I fix it? All I understand is the first error and that is I have to take separate permission for read phone state permission.

Error 1:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service beatbox.neelay.beatbox.MediaService: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10103 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2804)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1404)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10103 nor current process has android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE.
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1546)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1499)
at com.android.internal.telephony.ITelephonyRegistry$Stub$Proxy.listenForSubscriber(ITelephonyRegistry.java:544)
at android.telephony.TelephonyManager.listen(TelephonyManager.java:2514)
at beatbox.neelay.beatbox.MediaService.callStateListener(MediaService.java:612)
at beatbox.neelay.beatbox.MediaService.onCreate(MediaService.java:126)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2794)
... 9 more
```

This is the error that is submitted by the user.

Error 2:

```
Writing exception to parcel
  java.lang.SecurityException: 
    External path: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.android.providers.media/albumthumbs/1481126994678: Neither user 10199 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.
      at android.app.ContextImpl.enforce(ContextImpl.java:1443)
      at android.app.ContextImpl.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextImpl.java:1475)
      at android.content.ContextWrapper.enforceCallingOrSelfPermission(ContextWrapper.java:675)
      at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.enforceCallingOrSelfPermissionAndAppOps(MediaProvider.java:6793)
      at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.checkAccess(MediaProvider.java:5570)
      at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.ensureFileExists(MediaProvider.java:4381)
      at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.getAlbumArtOutputUri(MediaProvider.java:5834)
      at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.makeThumbInternal(MediaProvider.java:5976)
      at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.getThumb(MediaProvider.java:5897)
      at com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider.openFile(MediaProvider.java:5466)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1427)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1607)
      at android.content.ContentProvider.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:1673)
      at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openTypedAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:430)
      at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:313)
      at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:458)
```

I have take permission for Android m both in manifest and in Java, and I'm not using any function of write external storage but then also it is showing this error.

Comment: please consider to check permission.. Android 6 > need permission to use them..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android >=6.0, We have to request permission runtime.

Step1: add in AndroidManifest.xml file

Step2: Request permission.

Step3: Handle callback when you request permission.

Check this one: [Permission at Run Time](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html)

Edit: I think you have [similar Issue:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36545864/music-player-asking-for-write-external-storage-permission)

Comment: i m not using any function of write external storage but i am using read storage if u can guide me for any of the error it will be help full

Comment: Check my updated Answer. Someone already solved it, I think this is what you are looking for.

Comment: sir as u said the 2nd error is solved but can u guide me in the first one also.

Answer (score 1):

you must add this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

to AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 1):

It might be because some of the devices are running Android 6.0 or higher and others are not.

See https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

> If the device is running Android 5.1 or lower, or your app's target SDK is 22 or lower: If you list a dangerous permission in your manifest, the user has to grant the permission when they install the app; if they do not grant the permission, the system does not install the app at all.
>
> If the device is running Android 6.0 or higher, and your app's target SDK is 23 or higher: The app has to list the permissions in the manifest, and it must request each dangerous permission it needs while the app is running. The user can grant or deny each permission, and the app can continue to run with limited capabilities even if the user denies a permission request.

Comment: check the update question the app is working in some android m device but in some android L and M it is crashing